# the code of ajax dont work

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

first of all, sory for my english...

- the "func 0" is ajax.
- the "func 1" is a code of refresh ajax code every 1000 ms. when the code work its refresh the refesh.php page and send the text on it to the "bbb" div.
- the "func 2" is code that the member write text and then the text send to the send.php page (the text send to the mySQL) and then it show the text in the "aaa" div.

someone can help me understend why the code dont work?

- if i put in the page  just the "func 0" and the "func 1", everything works good.
- and if i put in the page  just the "func 0" and the "func 2", everything also works good.
- but if i put on the page all the 3 function, its not works. i dont know why whene the member try to send text its send the text to mySQL (func 2), but its show the text from **refresh.php** (func 1) on the **"aaa"** div (func 2), instead of showing the text that the member send to the "aaa" div.

i hope you'll be able to figure out what the problem was, I had a little hard to explain

---

**this is the codes:**

```
<!--- func 0 --->
<script>
function refresh(name, url, info, type)
{
var str;
if (type=="send") {
str = document.forms["aaa"]["txt"].value;
}
if (type=="send" && str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById(name).innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url+"?info="+str,true); // send the text to page
xmlhttp.send();  
return false;
}
</script>
<!--- end - func 0 --->


<!--- func 1 --->
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("refresh('bbb', 'refresh.php', '', 'refresh')", "1000");
</script>
<div id='bbb'> div to refresh at 1000 ms </div>
<!--- end - func 1 --->


<!--- func 2 --->
<form name='aaa' onsubmit="return refresh('aaa', 'send.php', '', 'send');" method='post'>
txt: <input type='text' name='txt' autofocus='autofocus'> <input type='submit' value=' send '>
</form>
<div id='aaa'> div that <b>*send*</b> txt to sql </div>
<!--- end - func 2 --->
```

Comment: Pieces/parts don't make much sense when it comes to troubleshooting. It would be much easier if this were in the form of a jsFiddle. Please try and set one up.

Comment: @DevlshOne Won't the AJAX same-origin policy prevent that from working?

Comment: are you getting any error anywhere? what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @Barmar If it gets to that point, probably. It would be nice to see the whole picture first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `xmlhttp` is being defined as a global variable, so if you happen to have two AJAX queries loading at the same time, they will interfere with each other. Use `var xmlhttp` to fix this.

That being said, you shouldn't support IE6 and even less so IE5. Just do this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url+"?info="+str,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: thanks its work!! =] but now i have enother problem. if the member try to sent text, for example "11111" its send and everything works good. but if after that he's try to sent enother text, for example "00000", it continue to send the first text (11111). how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have only one global `xmlhttp` variable. If you put both functions on the page, it can happen that they try to send two requests in parallel which will then interfere. Make it a local variable:

```
var xmlhttp = …
```